# Automatic VM deployment

Tags: java, vmware, virtualization, esx

I have an idea to streamline deployments of prototypes within our team using VMs. The idea would be that a developer would be able to deploy their artifacts to Maven, then use a Web interface to pull them onto a development VM for integration/regression testing. They would then be able to to push those artifacts to a reference system, and finally onto production.

I'm currently thinking of doing this myself using the vSphere Java API ( http://vijava.sourceforge.net/ ), and some simple scripting to grab artifacts from the Maven repository, configuration from SVN, and then start up a JBoss server. It feels like the kind of thing that may already be available though, has anyone heard of something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it the thing that Continuous Integration is made for? We have done similar stuffs by using [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html) and [Jira Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I'm looking in particular at application hosting rather than specifically at testing.

Comment: And what the problem? Testing isn't a goal of CI, it's only an part of it (and of development process).

We are deploying out apps after each commit (after testing).

CI can:
 1. gets sources from version control
 2. builds app
 3. test it
 4. makes target artifacts (jars, zips, etc)
 5. deploys/upload this artifacts to target servers